# Back button for my page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, back

I used this code in order to hid the errors.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorServer.aspx" mode="On" />
```

I want to have back button for my Error page and as the user push the button it goes to the page that the user came from that. It means each time the back URL will be different!
How can i add the back button in my page?
Thanks

Comment: What about the browser back button? Is it not working? +1

Comment: It is working!! but the customer insist on it!! You know the customers! :)

Comment: Hmm. Answers seems good. If any of this works please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the referring URL on your error page.

So your front end could have this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypBackLink" Text="Go Back" runat="server" />
```

And in your Page_Load event:

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
     hypBackLink.NavigateURL = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

Comment: it gave me this error:
Error 53 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink' does not contain a definition for 'NavigateURL' and no extension method 'NavigateURL' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\WebSite Project Asp.Net\Dr Etemad Journal\Vesion 7\IN USE Journal\Jornal\ErrorServer.aspx.cs 14 25 E:\...\Jornal\

Comment: Always keep in mind that C# is case sensitive- Use HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();